# Hibernate Envers not generating audit tables

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to implement a history feature for my business objects in a web-application. The "easiest" way seems to be using hibernate envers. When I set up my Entities with the `@Audited` annotation and run the application, the tables are not created (but should be, documentation says, hibernate will setup tables automatically).

By updating a object in DB i get this exception: `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`

I already tried to set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`. I also tried setting up tables by myself, but exception is still thrown.

Using Hibernate 4.2.3 and Oracle DB.

EDIT - 
Full Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: Sequence ist nicht vorhanden.

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:122)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:115)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3SaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3SaveEventListener.java:71)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
at org.hibernate.envers.revisioninfo.DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.saveRevisionData(DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.java:83)
at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.getCurrentRevisionData(AuditProcess.java:129)
at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.executeInSession(AuditProcess.java:106)
at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:155)
at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:62)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:699)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:321)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:613)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
at com.mycode.common.db.JPAServletFilter.doFilter(JPAServletFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.mycode.web.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:67)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at RemoteUserValve.invoke(RemoteUserValve.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, question updated.

Comment: Do you have `hibernate_sequence` created in your schema?

Comment: I created it now using `create sequence hibernate_sequence;` and I got a new error.

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: Tabelle oder View nicht vorhanden`  (table or view does not exist)

Should I create any tables manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a permission problem, the user which is accessing oracle database is not permitted to drop, create or alter tables.

Instead of changing permissions I [generated the needed schema with Ant](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-generateschema) and executed the DDL with a DB User. After Tomcat restart the auditing worked.